# Infinite binary stream via WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, streaming

I've been searching the web and looking at various WCF books without finding an answer - So now I try my luck here.

I'm creating a `WCF` service which exposes a number of methods to other stakeholders. One of these methods is a continuous stream of live data which will be serialized via MessagePack (See example below).

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyHappyStreamingService
{
    [OperationContract]
    Stream GetLiveDataOfDataPoints(string query);
}
```

My issue is that the `DataPointStorage.GetDataPoints()` yields a possible infinite stream of `DataPoints` which should be pushed into the output stream without buffering. But how? See my dummy code below.

```
public class MyHappyStreamingService : IMyHappyStreamingService
{
    public Stream GetLiveDataOfDataPoints(string query)
    {
        foreach (DataPoint dataPoint in DataPointStorage.GetDataPoints()) {
            // Push dataPoint into output stream
        }

        /* Return some output stream */
     }
}
```

How can I map a possible infinite stream (`IEnumerable`) to a `Stream` in WCF? If I am missing something or doing something totally wrong please correct me :)

Comment: maybe this helps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/large-data-and-streaming

Comment: @gnsanty: Thanks, but already it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this example: http://ryandavis.io/a-lazily-evaluated-stream-wrapper-for-ienumerable/ which solved my problem.